# grails domain constraints is not a map at runtime like docs suggest

Tags: grails

The docs say that depending on version, accessing Domain.constraints or Domain.constrainedProperties should give a Map of key values.

https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.5.4/ref/Domain%20Classes/constraints.html

> At runtime the static constraints property is a Map such that the keys in the Map are property names and the values associated with the keys are instances of ConstrainedProperty:

However, using 2.5+, accessing the constraints property at runtime doesn't give a map, but a closure, and I can't access the ConstrainedProperty instances.

I tried using grails class utils to access the static property also

```
GrailsClassUtils.getStaticFieldValue(Domain,"constraints")//this is still a closure

GrailsClassUtils.getStaticFieldValue(Domain,"constrainedProperties")//null, this property doesn't exist below version 3.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Property access doesn't work for me like the example in the docs

```
Domain.constraints //returns closure
```

but using the method getter does

```
Domain.getConstraints() //returns the map
```

Answer (score 0):

See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/constraintsmapdemo.

https://github.com/jeffbrown/constraintsmapdemo/blob/master/grails-app/domain/demo/Widget.groovy:

```
package demo

class Widget {
    int width
    int height
    static constraints = {
        width range: 1..100
        height range: 1..50
    }
}
```

The test at https://github.com/jeffbrown/constraintsmapdemo/blob/master/test/unit/demo/WidgetSpec.groovy passes:

```
package demo

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(Widget)
class WidgetSpec extends Specification {

    void "test accessing the constraints property"() {
        when:
        def propValue = Widget.constraints

        then:
        propValue instanceof Map
        propValue.containsKey 'width'
        propValue.containsKey 'height'
    }
}
```

If you are not using static compilation, `Widget.constraints` will evaluate to the `Map`.  If you are using static compilation, `Widget.getConstraints()` will return the `Map` but `Widget.constraints` will evaluate to the closure.